# Connect to Android Emulator from Host

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I am developing a `Xamarin App` that runs on `Android`, so my toolchain consists of `Visual Studio` and the `Android Emulator` system.

When I want to connect to my host machine from `Android`, I can use the alias `10.0.2.2`.

The other way around - from Host to `Android` I cannot connect.

Using the `IP` address from `Android` network settings: no success.
Using the `IP` adresses from the `adb shell ifconfig` result: no success.

How can I connect to the `Android` system with normal network protocols (no ADB logs, etc.)?
Maybe some kind of `ADB shell` command to create port forwardings?

Comment: Hi, do you mean can not connecting to android emulator by adb ? Having a try with restarting adb server: **adb kill-server -> adb start-server**.

Comment: Hi, adb connecting to Android is no problem. The issue is to connect from an application on the host to the running Android in the emulator (like an Android app provides a REST api I want to access from host)

Comment: Okey , have you checked with postman to get data from Rest Api ? If this works , please let me know.

Comment: I cannot establish a network connection from host to android, that is the key problem

Comment: First you need a rest api , then android device can get data from api. Here is an article can be refer to.https://android.jlelse.eu/consuming-rest-api-in-xamarin-android-using-refit-4e73c456f30c

Comment: @junior: you are misunderstanding the problem. REST was an example- this would be the REST server running on the Android in an emulator. I want to consume the REST Api via a client on the host. But i cannot get a network connection from host to android

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding .But why need android device to create a REST server ?  I want to know the advantage of doing this first.

Comment: There are several apps and use-cases - joint network discovery for shared services, mobile device for POS with rest-based access or integrated tiny web service for configuration. There are more use-cases possible and there are apps in the store having similiar concepts - for development with the emulator a network connection is required

Comment: Got it. You can have a try with Socket to connect to pos device. If POS device has documents how to connect , that will be more clearly to do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

Comment: In this example, the app on the android device is the POS - indepentend from havin a rest server, a socket or else - I cannot connect to the android.

Comment: I think that in network communication, at least one of the IP addresses needs to be fixed. Generally, the IP of the server is fixed. Therefore, when the client connects to the server, it can be connected by IP address. In your question, if the Android device acts as a server, you need to know the IP of the device.

Comment: This is exactly the question I am asking. What is the IP adress? I see IP information inside Android and from requesting the adb shell - but those are not working (no firewall active)

Comment: Okey , if want to get device's IP, I have updated an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If want to get **IP** from Molile , you can have a try with follow methods:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;

var IpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault();

if (IpAddress != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP is :" + IpAddress.ToString());
}
```

**Note:**

If they (Android Emulator and Android Device) are not on the same network segment, then it is impossible to connect.

Comment: This returns just the IP Adress, that the Android system is knowing about (e.g. the emulated WiFi) - so the same as the result from Android settings and the adb result. It is not working for connections from host to the Android system.

Comment: @auX Generally, first need client connect to host , then host will remember which client is connectted.

Comment: I can connect from android to the host by using the IP 10.0.2.2, which is a well-defined alias from the emulator system, but I want to use a web browser/REST Client/etc. from the host machine, which is hosting the android emulator to connect to the android emulator. For this, this not working

Comment: @auX Do they connect with WIFI NetWork ? Have a look at this : https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct May be helpful.

Comment: No, the Android connects to the emulated WiFi of the Android emulator, not an actual WiFi

Comment: @auX Okey, if they are not on the same network segment, then it is impossible to connect.

Comment: That is the question - Vice versa, from Android to host, there is the possibility for connections, so I am searching whether there is a way for my purpose

Comment: @auX Here is an article about *COMMUNICATION OVER WIFI IN ANDROID* . https://www.yudiz.com/communication-over-wifi-in-android/  This is a communication between two android devices ,Or one is just offer WiFi hotspot to android device.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection

> **Using network redirection**
>
> To communicate with an emulator instance behind its virtual router, you need to set up network redirection on the virtual router. Clients can then connect to a specified guest port on the router, while the router directs traffic to/from that port to the emulated device host port.
>
> To set up the network redirection, you create a mapping of host and guest ports/addresses on the emulator instance. There are two ways to set up network redirection: using emulator console commands and using the adb tool, as described below.

See the link for full instructions.